# How to convert Eigen::eigenvector().col(0).real() to std vector?

Tags: c++, vector, eigen, eigenvector

I am working on a code in c++ that calulates the eigen vectors of a matrix using the Eigen library. I need only the first column and only the real values of the eigen vector. Is there a way to copy these values to the `std::vector` data type? Can someone help me with this?

I saw this [Converting Eigen::MatrixXf to 2D std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242460/converting-eigenmatrixxf-to-2d-stdvector) post. But I need only the specific values. Moreover, I am not sure what is the type that `eigenvector()` function returns. In the documentation, it is said as complex `Eigen::Matrix` type.

This is an example code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Eigen/Eigenvalues>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

struct eigen
{
    float a, b, c;
};

int main()
{
    vector<Eigen::Matrix3f> A(1);
    A[0] << 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 5, 6;
    Eigen::EigenSolver<Eigen::Matrix3f> handle(A[0]);
    cout << "The matrix of eigenvectors, V, is: " << endl << handle.eigenvectors() << endl << endl;
    cout << "The real part of first column is : " << endl << 
    handle.eigenvectors().col(0).real() << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above code is

```
The matrix of eigenvectors, V, is:
 (0.327985,0) (-0.736977,0) (-0.591009,0)
 (0.591009,0) (-0.327985,0)  (0.736976,0)
 (0.736976,0)  (0.591009,0) (-0.327985,0)

The real part of the first column is :
0.327985
0.591009
0.736976
```

I need to copy the values of `handle.eigenvectors().col(0).real()` to `std::vector<eigen>`

Comment: Your matrix appears to be symmetrical. Consider using [`SelfAdjointEigenSolver`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SelfAdjointEigenSolver.html). And for 3x3 matrices you can also use `computeDirect()`, for faster computation.

Comment: Why do you have `std::vector`s of a single element? It sounds like you want to copy the three values from `handle.eigenvectors()` to a single `eigen` object

Comment: @Caleth This is just an example. I have millions of such symmetric 3 * 3 matrices for which i need to compute eigen vectors and I would like to store the results in a vector for further computation.

Comment: @chtz Thanks, my matrices were symmetric. That was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Map](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMapClass.html) is the answer:

```
 Vector3f::Map(&v[0].a) = handle.eigenvectors().col(0).real();
```

Comment: This is undefined behaviour. You are pretending there is a `float[3]` where none exists

Comment: Works like a charm in my case. My output size is fixed for me. So it will always return 3 float. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add a constructor and/or an assignment operator to `eigen` that copies the values.

```
struct eigen
{
    eigen() = default;
    template <typename InputIterator, typename = std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type>
    eigen(InputIterator first) : a(*first++), b(*first++), c(*first++) {}
    template <typename InputIterator, typename = std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type>
    eigen& operator=(InputIterator first)
    {
        a = *first++;
        b = *first++;
        c = *first++;
        return *this;
    }
    float a, b, c;
};

int main()
{
    Eigen::Matrix3f A;
    A << 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 5, 6;
    Eigen::EigenSolver<Eigen::Matrix3f> handle(A);
    std::cout << "The matrix of eigenvectors, V, is: " << std::endl << handle.eigenvectors() << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The real part of first column is : " << std::endl << 
    handle.eigenvectors().col(0).real() << std::endl << std::endl;

    eigen e = handle.eigenvectors().col(0).real();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I got the following error ```error: conversion from ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<float>, 3, 3>, 3, 1, true> >::NonConstRealReturnType {aka Eigen::CwiseUnaryView<Eigen::internal::scalar_real_ref_op<std::complex<float> >, Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<float>, 3, 3>, 3, 1, true> >}’ to non-scalar type ‘eigen’ requested
  eigen e = handle.eigenvectors().col(0).real();```

Comment: I used g++ compiler with -std=c++11 flag